# Android Studio freezes on "Initializing ADB..."

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio can freeze at any moment. And every time afer re-starting it again freezes on "Initializing ADB...". Only re-starting of PC helps to solve the problem. I have 8GB RAM.

I increased size of memory in 4 times in studio64.exe.vmoptions but it didn't help:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx2560m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1400m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=900m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.3
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: you may start many programs in your background

Comment: Are you using adb elsewhere, too? Have you tried to stop or restart adb on command line when AS hangs?

Comment: Rene M., thanks, I've forgot to try it) i'v made adb kill-server, adb start-server and it fixed freezing on "Initializing ADB...". But anyway suddenly freezeing it's not fixed

Comment: Hassan Usman, mosty system tasks in background. Used CPU %3, RAM 62%

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Disconnect the device that is connect. And then the Initializing would stop. And then you can reconnect the device. Works for me every single time

Comment: There is a special spot for you in heaven.

Comment: Nope, intializing didn't even stop after disconnecting the device :(

Comment: Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Important point to note that ADB works normally, so the bug is at AS side.

Answer (score 4):

Reconnect and restart adb-server does not help.

My fault is deleted the localhost config in /etc/hosts.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

after adding this line to /etc/hosts, everything works fine.

Note that maybe you have installed some hosts auto config software. Just make sure ping localhost in the terminal and see 127.0.0.1 on screen.

Comment: Awesome. You saved my months. Really perfect answer. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing this issue.

I just resolve this issue by restarting Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing it.
Sometimes the IDE fails to access the folder ADB is contained in. Try running the application as an administrator.